# Dynamic links in Drupal

Tags: drupal

This must be an easy one but I can't find documentation for it online.

I'm trying to use the l() function in Drupal to create a dynamic link. What's the syntax?

At the moment I have:

```
l('Destination',"path/$user->uid/category")
```

which points to:

```
path/%2Fcategory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all, if you're working within a function, you'll need to get access to the global user object.

Secondly, if the user is anonymous/not logged in, the $user->uid might not be set or be 0.

lastly to prevent errors, it is common to concatenate variables together with strings

```
global $user;
if ($user->uid)
{
  l('Destination', 'path/'.$user->uid.'/category')
}
```

Comment: That was it (global access to the user object). Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

`l()` is correcting your URL to `path/%2Fcategory` because it's trying to make a workable link from the string `path//category`.

Your string is `path//category` because `$user->uid` has no value. It has no value because either you haven't pulled up a user object from `global $user` or `user_load()`, or your user is anonymous.

I would suggest putting checking the value of $user before calling `l()`, for example:

```
global $user; // or $user = user_load($foo);
if ($user) {
l('Destination', 'path/'.$user->uid.'/category');
} else {
l('Destination', 'path/you-are-not-logged-in');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating the strings instead.
`l('Destination',"path/".$user->uid."/category")`

as for the documentation, here it is: http://api.drupal.org/api/function/l/4.7

```
l($text, 
   $path, 
   $attributes = array(), 
   $query = NULL, 
   $fragment = NULL, 
   $absolute = FALSE, 
   $html = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'd already tried that, but it gives the same outcome. It seems the l() function is both refusing to deal with the variable and escaping the second slash.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation for the l() function is located at:
http://api.drupal.org/api/function/l/6

Other stuff has been said yet by others :)